# Firefox doesnt see java plugin

Tags: windows, firefox, java, plugins

I work on a machine without administrator access. There is java installed on it however Firefox doesn't pick it up somehow. IE has no problems running Java content however. My question is how can I force Firefox to use already installed Java without reinstalling anything?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the java extension for Firefox. You can ask your administrator to do this.  You have to install something.